# Fading out a video Div if the first menu is not Active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm customising a Wordpress theme and have added a background video. The page has custom links with control a slider. I'm trying to get the video to fade out if your not on the first slide (.nav-Intro) but everything I;ve tried fails!

http://www.boytoballer.com/wp/

Please help?

```
if ($('.nav-Intro').classList.contains("swiper__nav-active")) {
   $('.btb-home-vid').fadeIn(1000);
}  else {
     $('.btb-home-vid').fadeOut(1000);
}
```

Comment: I've also tried this (below) but still not working, do I need to add a listener or something?

Comment: if(!$(".link").hasClass('.nav-Intro.swiper__nav-active')){ 
 $('.btb-home-vid').fadeIn(1000);
}else {
 $('.btb-home-vid').fadeOut(1000);
 }

Comment: This one almost works but doesn't fade backin when I hover on the first link - $( ".link" ).on( "hover", function() {
 if(!$(".link").hasClass('nav-Intro')){ 
 $('.btb-home-vid').fadeIn(1000);
}else {
 $('.btb-home-vid').fadeOut(1000);
 }
});

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!
Had to change second ".link.f5" to (THIS)

```
$( ".link.f5" ).on( "hover", function() {

if ($(this).hasClass('nav-Intro')){ 
    $('.btb-home-vid').fadeIn(1000);
}  else {
    $('.btb-home-vid').fadeOut(1000);
    }

});
```